# Install ubuntu to Notebook through SD Card with only 128Mb or Ram?

Tags: laptop

Can I / Will It be Possible to install Ubuntu ( Any version at all ) On an CnM Book That is currently running Windows CE V5.00 ? 2009 Build. Would be Much Appriciated. Laptop / Notebook has 128MB of RAM 2GB SSD and is running @266Mhz

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi

Answer (score 0):

It is not the safest or best idea to install Ubuntu (yes, any version) on a computer with 128MB of RAM and a 2GB SSD. I would recommend something like Puppy Linux or even Tiny Core Linux, but no Ubuntu Version can Support that hardware. As for installing, it should work with an SD, as long as you have access to BIOS. Hope this helps!

Comment: Ubuntu server edition works fine on computers with only 128MB of RAM. The issue is with the standard installer, which jumped up in memory requirements by about 64 megabytes, to about 165 megabytes, during the 14.04 cycle.

Comment: @DougSmythies the mini.iso is the answer to that https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Comment: what about debian? heck, I installed debian based antixos with no trouble on my old win98 pc http://antix.mepis.org/index.php?title=Main_Page

Answer (score 0):

Some research indicates that the model with the specs you've provided is a CPU that is ARM. Given that the specs are so low this also really limits your choices because you will probably want something already compiled for the architecture.

What I have found is that SLiTaz has a Linux version that is aimed at the Raspberry Pi (a handy little critter with ARM CPUs). I have absolutely no way to check to verify this but you can try this if you're daring.

http://arm.slitaz.org/rpi/

Another option is to use the search function at DistroWatch and see what pops up and looks interesting - keep in mind that you're very limited. 2 GB of space isn't much these days. (I'd seriously consider getting/installing on a USB thumb drive if I had to use that hardware.)

I've already selected a couple of options for you (Linux and ARM) but you can select your own options and keep searching from there. Here's a link:

http://distrowatch.com/search.php?ostype=Linux&category=All&origin=All&basedon=All&notbasedon=None&desktop=All&architecture=arm&package=All&rolling=All&status=Active

**Edit:** As mentioned below there's also a Ubuntu ARM based distro (for, again, PI) that you *might* want to try as well. Given the size of the ecosystem that Ubuntu has you may just want to try that first. The link is here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi

Comment: there's also an ubuntu version available for raspberry pi https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi

Comment: @mchid - Cool, I did not know that. I'll add it to my post.